# A Python script run well on Jupyter Notebook but not as .py script?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a very simple code of 3 functions in Python. I can input three variables, and the code generates and exports a csv file to my laptop. Everything runs very well, including exporting part, on my JupyterNotebook. But once I saved the code as python script ending with .py, and run on Windows by simply double-clicking, the script is opened, takes all the inputs and then closed command window. It can't export any file I want. What happened here?

```
def get_chains(input1,input2,input3):
    import pymysql
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    connection=pymysql.connect...
    ...
    df=pd.read_sql(sql_cmd,connection)
    connection.close()

    def total_rewards(num):
       ....
    def calculator(df,path_output):
       .....


    return calculator(df,input3)


input1 = input('input first date:')
input2 = input('input second date:')
input3 = input('file path and name:')
get_chains(input1,input2,input3)
```

input1 and 2 are simply restrictions on dates.
it should pull data from our database, do calculations on the data and export to the desired path (input3). I made sure to include .csv as the file ending.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. And what exactly is the error returned by the interpreter? It seems to me you are discarding it, open a terminal window and run your script with `python my-script.py`, instead of double clicking the file.

Answer (score 0):

you should run your *.py file in command prompt and check what happens (get the error). For that: press Win+R, type `cmd`, next go to location where your *.py script is: `cd %PATH_TO_FOLDER_WITH_PY%`, and finally - type `python %your_script_name%.py` - you'll be able to see all the errors.

Answer (score -1):

Got it! I did what you guys suggested, and it turned out that I didnt have necessary packages installed. Thank you so much!